# default value to a cell of a new row without a macro (Excel)

Tags: excel, row, default-value

I would like to insert a default value, to a specific cell in my worksheet,
but this default value should take care of new rows inserted in the worksheet.

I must **not** use a macro for this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but I can not think of any way, one would be able to that. This is more a typicall database functionality. Without macros you would have to use a function or a format. A function, like values, would not be copied by inserting new rows - only formats would, so this narrows it down.

By the way, I interpreted your question to "default value on instertion of new row", not "default value when writing data in a existing clear row".

So, as a kind of "default value behaviour" you could use user defined cellformats.

i.e. use `;;'x';` as a user format and format your cell or column with it. This won't fill empty cells with 'x' but, whenever you would type in '0' it would change to 'x'.

However, I am very interested, if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation to cells which can help you force a number into a particular cell, but as stated in the earlier answer a database is more designed for Default Values.

It seems to me you are trying to create a database in Excel, I wouldn't recommend this as excel is very good at prototyping algorithms however when it comes to structuring tables it can fail very quickly.

Use at least MS Access, namely as it comes with a database. Alternatives are rapid prototyping tool such as Eclipse or Netbeans, or Visual Studio if your budget can stretch that far.  Couple the RAD tools with MySql (namely for ease of use and the fact that the community licence is good) and the system should be stable.